# how to exclude a string date formattee from being tested against another string?

Tags: java, android

I am retrieving a list of dates. One by one and testing them against another date for mated
    August 27,2011
I have dates for mated in two ways.

```
August 27,2011
August 2011.
```

How could I exclude testing the date formatted August 2011? When I try to parse it it will give me a paserexception. So how could I exclude these dates formatted that way?

EDIT:

```
 date = postIt.next().text();
                     Log.v("Dates", date);

                     try {
                        Date itemDate = sdf.parse(date);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


 if(itemDate.equals(isToday)){
                             nm = (NotificationManager) this
                                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                      CharSequence from = "app";
                                      CharSequence message = message";
                                      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Example.class), 0);
                                      Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                                               message , System.currentTimeMillis());
                                              notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, contentIntent);
                                              nm.notify(1, notif);


                         }

                         else{
```

Comment: how about using a regex?

Comment: could you give a little more details

Comment: what do you mean "testing them against another date" ?

Comment: don't use `toString()` for that. Can you show your code?

Comment: Define `Date itemDate = null` outside the try/catch. Otherwise it's not visible below

Comment: I do, just didn't post it. Am I doing what you suggest the correct way?

Comment: Am i doing it the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the parse exception - this will indicated incorrectly formatted date according to your expectations. For example:

```
for (String dateString : dateStrings) {
     try {
          Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
     } catch (ParseException ex) {
         // date can't be parsed, ignore & continue. 
     }
}
```

Comment: ive tried that but it doesn't continue if the date isnr fornstted correctly

Comment: if the date is formatted correctly how will it continue comparing it? Could you show an example in code if you have

Comment: So is that for() comparing the Date to the dateStrings?

Comment: that's a loop I assume you have, because you haven't shown anything of your code

Comment: I was using if() statements. It would probably work better to us for, what do you think?

Comment: I cannot have an opinion on code that I can't see ;) when you said "one by one", I assumed a loop.

Comment: How coukd I have it to continue checking the dates once it get caught that the date couldn't be parsed?

Comment: Hmmmm soon...if the date is August 2011 what should I parse it to? I can't just skip the dates for mated with only August 2011?